# WooCommerce Free Shipping Issue: Multiple Radio Buttons Dilemma on Orders Over free shipping price

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart, webshop

I have set up a WordPress site with WooCommerce.

My goal is to offer free shipping for orders over €75.

On its own, it works fine, but I'm encountering a small issue. If I have a product that costs €30 in my cart and then add more products, bringing the total above €75, suddenly two radio buttons for free shipping appear, instead of just showing one for free shipping. If I then increase the quantity again, it goes back to displaying the correct output.

This is my code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'update_shipping_rates_based_on_total', 10, 2);

function update_shipping_rates_based_on_total($rates, $package) {
    $price_limit = 75;

    // Check if the cart total is €75 or above
    if (WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total() >= $price_limit) {
        // Set cost for free shipping
        foreach ($rates as $rate_id => $rate) {
            $rates[$rate_id]->cost = 0;
            $rates[$rate_id]->label = 'Gratis verzending';
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}

// Clear shipping rates cache when the cart is updated
add_action('woocommerce_after_cart', 'clear_shipping_rates_cache');

function clear_shipping_rates_cache() {
    WC()->shipping()->reset_shipping();
}
```

Here are the images to make it clearer:
[image][image][image]

Comment: you wrote `foreach ($rates as $rate_id => $rate) {` meaning all shipping options will be ovewritten with cost = 0 and label = "Gratis verzending". If you comment out your hook, you should see 2 choices in the shipping box, right?

Comment: No, that is not the problem, the issue is, why it is showing the radio buttons.
Image 2 should show like image 3.
But somehow when you jump over the free shipping rate it shows the radiobuttons, but on the next step it shows it properly.
So what might cause this showing radio buttons?

Comment: what happens if you comment out your hook and reproduce the exact same sequence? I suspect you will see different shipping options for different price rates, reflecting the number of "duplicate" options you see when the hook is applied. Can you please verify that?

Comment: What happens than it has the same behaving expect that it is showing than the flat rate on all prices even if you have more than the min rate of 75 in this case.
So that doesn't seems to be the problem.
It had some seems to have a mechanism that somehow add the radiobuttons when getting over 75. really annoying this